# What is m1type parameter in OpenCV's UndistortRectifyMap()

Tags: python, opencv

I am trying to use OpenCV's `initUndistortRectifyMap()` function to create a map that undistorts a fish-eye image, as outlined in [this tutorial](http://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_calib3d/py_calibration/py_calibration.html)

The tutorial has this line of code:

```
mapx,mapy = cv2.initUndistortRectifyMap(mtx,dist,None,newcameramtx,(w,h),5)
```

But when my script reaches that line, the following error is thrown:

> OpenCV errror: Assertion failed (m1type == CV_16SC2 || m1type ==
>   CV_32FC1 || m1type == CV32FC2) in initUndistortedRectifyMap, file
>   /hdd/buildbot/slave_jetson_tx_3/35-04T-L4T-R24/opencv/modules/imgproc/src/undistort.cpp

The source of the error appears to be the '5' in the last argument, which, according to the [documentation](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#initundistortrectifymap), is the "**m1type** – Type of the first output map that can be CV_32FC1 or CV_16SC2." What do these different types mean, and how do I know what the correct value is for my program?

(Note: I am aware of the cv2.undistort() function, but it does not work for my purposes.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The assertion states that the `m1type` must be one of : `CV_16SC2`, `CV_32FC1` or  `CV_32FC2`, and you are passing it as `5`. The integral values of these constants as of OpenCV 2 are mapped as

> CV_16SC2 - 11
>
> CV_32FC1 - 5
>
> CV_32FC2 - 13

That is why in the documentation you were referring, the author has used `5` to signify the `CV_32FC1`, However it is a bad choice, You must use `CV_32FC1` or `mat.type()` to get the type of mat, and avoid using any such numerical constants.

Answer (score 1):

A part of my confusion was about the 'm1type.' This refers to the type of value stored in an OpenCV's Mat objects. The format of the name is as follows:
`CV_[The number of bits per item][Signed or Unsigned][Type Prefix]C[The channel number]` ([source](http://www.bogotobogo.com/OpenCV/opencv_3_tutorial_creating_mat_objects.php))

So, for example, 'CV_16SC2' is 16 bits, signed, and 2 channels.